# Difference between pre and post decrement in recursive function argument

Tags: c++, recursion, post-increment, pre-increment

I have following sample code where i used pre-decrement

```
void function(int c)
{
  if(c == 0)
  {
     return;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "DP" << c << endl;
    function(--c);
    cout << c << endl;
    return;
  }
}
```

This function give output for input 4 as :

```
 DP3
 DP2
 DP1
 DP0
 0
 1
 2
 3
```

But when i use post decrement

```
void function(int c)
{
  if(c == 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "DP" << c << endl;
    function(c--);
    cout << c << endl;
    return;
  }
}
```

Output goes in infinite loop with DP4

Can you explain me in detail why this happens ?

Comment: This happens because function(c--) will be called with the same value of c and when it finishes c will be decremented. But as it is recursively called, hence it will be called with same value with no chance of return and eventually you will hit stack overflow error.

Comment: Can you explain me how exactly pre and post works ?

Comment: Assume this,  int x = 1, y = 0;  Now y = x++  will result y == 1 and x == 2. But if you do y = ++x ,  then bot x and y will be 2.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar Please add your explanation in answer so that i can upvote you

Comment: When doing recursion it's better not to mutate the variable. eg. you can do `function(c-1)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because function(c--) will be called with the same value of c and when it finishes c will be decremented. But as it is recursively called, hence it will be called with same value with no chance of return and eventually you will hit stack overflow error.

Assume this, int x = 1, y = 0; Now y = x++ will result y == 1 and x == 2. But if you do y = ++x , then bot x and y will be 2.

Answer (score 5):

Because `--c` will return `c-1`,however `c--` return `c`.So when you use `function(c--)` is equal to `function(c);c = c-1;`.`c` will never be `0`.So the function won't stop.
To know the difference between `--x` and `x--` you can try the following code:

```
int x = 5,y=5;
cout<<x--<<endl;
cout<<--y<<endl;
cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
```

Comment: 1+ for quick and detail explanation

Answer (score 1):

In case of post decrement value will be passed before decrement , always same value will be passed to function , it never come out .

function(c--), first it call function(c)  later decrement c-- will happen .

Comment: 1+ for quick and detail explanation